# Повторное срабатывание функции

Tags: c++, функции, динамические-массивы

Я создаю программу, которая создает двумерный массив, заполняет его пользовательскими элементами и выводит сумму отрицательных. По непонятной мне причине фнукция borders срабатывает два раза, не понимаю, в чем загвоздка?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int borders(int x[2]) {
    int n, m;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;

    if (n > 10 | m > 10) {
        cout<<"n and m must be <= 10"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        x[0] = n;
        cout<<"n=";
        cout<<n<<endl;
        x[1] = m;
        cout<<"m=";
        cout<<m<<endl;
    }
    return *x;
}

int** input(int x[2]) {
    int n, m;
    borders(x);
    n = x[0];
    m = x[1];
    int **a = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a[i] = new int[m];
    return a;
}

int calc(int** a, int x[2]) {
    int n = x[0], m = x[1];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] < 0)
                sum += a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void show(int sum) {
    cout<<"Sum="<<endl;
    cout<<sum;
}

int main() {
    int sum;
    int** a;
    int x[] = {};
    borders(x);
    input(x);
    calc(a, &x[2]);
    show(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: условие n > 10 | m > 10  есть ошибка, а код  ужас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И у вас явно проблемы с использованием массивов. Программа случайно не рушится?
Сначала вы объявляете пустой массив, а потом передаете его в функцию как массив из 2 элементов. А потом записываете на это место значения и хотите их использовать в другой функции. Более того, вы пытаетесь по этим данным выделить память в `input()`.

```
int borders(int x[2]) // здесь int x[2] - локальный массив
{
  x[0] = n;  // данные не выйдут за пределы функции borders()
  x[1] = m;
}

int main() 
{
    int x[] = {};  // пустой массив
    borders(x);    // передается по копии как int x[2]
    input(x);
```

Чтобы не было неопределенного поведения UB (крах программы), должно быть например так:

```
int borders(int* x) {}

int main() 
{
    int x[] = { 0, 0};  // массив из 2 элементов
    borders(x);    // передается указатель на массив
```

Функция  `calc( , int x[2])` принимает указатель на массив int из 2 элементов. А передаете вы в неё адрес второго элемента массива. Дальше вы получите UB (скорее всего - крах программы) по 2 причинам:

- адресация элементов самого `x[2]`
- адресация элементов массива `a` относительно значений, хранящихся в `x`

```
int calc(int** a, int x[2])
{  int n = x[0], 
       m = x[1]; // здесь UB
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i; i < n; i++) // n и m не соответствуют ранее помещенным в x[0]  и x[1] значениям, 
        for (int j; j < m; j++) 
        {
            if (a[i][j] < 0) // в результате выход за пределы массива a
                sum += a[i][j];
        }

int main() {
    calc(a, &x[2]); // вы передаете адрес второго элемента массива
```

В функции `calc()` не инициализируете итераторы i j начальными значениями

```
int calc() {
    for (int i; i < n; i++) { // чему равно i в самом начале???
        for (int j; j < m; j++) { // чему равно j в самом начале???
```

Ну и по-мелочам - в операторе `if()` у вас не `логическое или` а `побитовое или`. Логическое или пишется `||`. Или используйте синоним `or`

```
if (n > 10 | m > 10) // неправильно!!!
// должно быть
if (n > 10 || m > 10)
// или
if (n > 10 or m > 10)
```

Непонятный возврат в функции `borders()` - возвращаете значение x[0]. Спасает только то, что возвращаемое значение нигде не используется. А зачем тогда было писать функцию, что-то возвращающую?

```
int borders(int x[2]) 
{
   return *x;
}
```

Comment: Не передаётся массив в функцию по копии. Записи `int borders(int x[2])` и `int borders(int* x)` эквивалентны: в обоих случаях параметр `x` имеет тип `int*`.

Comment: @wololo Да, действительно, что-то загнался я. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый комменатрий! Получилось поправить все ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто. В функции `main` написаны строки

```
borders(x);  <---
input(x);
```

Это первый вызов.

И в функции  `input`  написаны строчки

```
int n, m;
borders(x); <---
```

Это второй вызов